# Hamiltonian groups in GAP

Tags: gap

Is there any command in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) to generate a Hamiltonian group of an order given?

I'm looking for in [GAP-Reference Manual](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html), but i don't find anything.

[Bujalance, Etayo & Gamboa](https://www.librosuned.com/LU40/Teor%C3%ADa-elemental-de-grupos-.aspx) define a Hamiltonian group like a kind of group wich all subgroups are normal subgroups.

Comment: Regarding the structure of a H. group, it would be a case that you give any arbitrary order and want GAP to call the group of the kind.

Comment: There isn't such a function per se, but as the structure of Hamiltonian groups is just a direct product of $Q_8$ with a suitable abelian group, they could be constructed easily that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments.

Comment: This function may be useful to determinate if the group is hamiltonian:
Hamiltonian:=function(G)
ls:=AllSubgroups(G);;
nm:=Filtered(ls,n-> IsNormal(G,n));;
a:=nm=ls;;
Print(a);
end;